# Copy paste from site "x" to site "y"

Tags: html, text, encoding

Case: a client copies a numerical payment code from a public site to the input on the form on "my" site. The problem is as follows: the validation says that the input needs 30 characters (although copied code is already 30), BUT when he deletes and re-writes a digit the validation passes, form is submitted and everyone is happy.

The html input is of type ="text", it has a min-max of 30 characters and a regex pattern to ensure all input are numbers.

I cannot reproduce the problem to get a hint on whats going on amd give a logical explanation.

Comment: I think you're copying the spaces around that code, that's why it's making it more-than 30 characters.

Comment: i checked that but sadly this is not the case.. it has an onBlur js function that removes whitespace where ever it finds it.